# Convert array of dictionaries into usable JSON

Tags: arrays, json, swift, dictionary

I am having trouble creating a JSON object that embeds an array of dictionaries. Here is non-working code of what I want to do. The myMessages in parameters throws an error:

```
let myMessages: [Dictionary: Any?] = [
    { role: "system", content: "You’re a social media manager writing Instagram captions." },
    { role: "user", content: "I want to post something on Instagram on Mother’s day. Brainstorm some ideas." },
]
 
let parameters: [String: Any?] = [
    "model": model,
    "messages": myMessages,
]
guard let parametersJson = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: .prettyPrinted) else { 
    return
}
```

**Edit:**

I can get it to compile and run if I change myMessages to a dict as follows but the API requires an array.

```
var myMessages = ["role": "user", "content": "How many days in a week"]
```

**Edit 2**
Using the accepted answer and comments below the following code works properly. As pointed out the problems were: Proper way to declare the array is [[String: Any?]], curly braces do not work in Swift and keys if strings not variables need to be in quotes.

```
var myMessages: [[String: Any?]] = [
            [ "role": "system", "content": "You love pizza." ],
            [ "role": "user", "content": "What do you think of pizza" ]
        ]
```

Comment: Don't use `try?`. Use `try` inside a `do/catch` block and put `print(error)` in the `catch` block. Then you'll know why it's failing instead of ignoring the error.

Comment: It is not yet compiling in order to run it

Comment: What are `role` and `content` in your dictionaries? Almost everything about your declaration and initialization of `myMessage` is wrong. Swift doesn't use curly braces for dictionaries. And the declaration `[Dictionary: Any?]` doesn't make much sense either. That's saying that you want a dictionary where the keys are of type `Dictionary` and the values are of type `Any?`. You want something more like `[[String: Any?]]`.

Comment: You can easily make that an array by putting another set of brackets (`[]`) around it. So you'll have double brackets: i.e. `[["foo": "bar"], ["baz": "qux"]]`

Comment: The extra brackets did the job! Thank you.

Comment: If I want to put two messages in the array, how would you add a second one eg [["foo": "bar","baz": "qux"], ["foo": "bat","baz":"zzz"]]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The declaration of your `myMessages` variable isn't valid Swift:

1. The type doesn't make sense. It looks like you want an array of dictionaries, but `[Dictionary : Any?]` would give you a single dictionary, which would be mapping keys of type `Dictionary` (which itself is not valid without generic parameters) to `Any?` values. What you probably want is `[[String : Any]]`, which would be an array (hence the outer brackets) of dictionaries with String keys (i.e. `[String : Any]`).
2. Curly braces are correct to define a dictionary in raw JSON, but not in Swift. Swift uses square brackets for that. Replace the `{` and `}` with `[` and `]`.
3. Your dictionary keys need to be correctly formatted as strings; i.e. `"role":` rather than `role:`, unless of course `role` is a variable pointing to some string key.